# How do I populate a QTableView with asynchronous fetched data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to populate a QTableView with some fetched data (using for example a database- or network-request) upon its creation. Because the request takes some time - thus blocking the GUI - I came to the conclusion to use another thread for fetching.

My current setup looks like this (obviously simplified):

```
class MyTable : public QTableView {
    QFutureWatcher<QAbstractItemModel*>* watcher;

    void init() {
        watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QAbstractItemModel*>();
        connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onResult()));
        watcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(...))
    }

    void onResult() {
        setModel(watcher->result());
    }
}
```

The init()-methode is called after the object has been added to the GUI. Because I am quite new to C++ / Qt / Multithreading, I wanted to ask if this code behaves as expected or if I may run into some kind of race condition or the like. I'm especially concerned about the onResult()-method, because I fear "setModel" might not be thread safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to subclass the view if the model is loading its data asynchronously. This has nothing to do with the view's behavior.

**The whole purpose of the [Model/View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) pattern is to decouple the model and the view components** to increase flexibility and reuse. By subclassing the view like that, **You are coupling them again.**

> I'm especially concerned about the onResult()-method, because I fear "setModel" might not be thread safe.

**You are right**, `setModel` is not thread-safe. You shouldn't touch any `QWidget` from a thread other than the main thread, see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy). But, **`onResult` method is guaranteed to be called in the thread where the view lives** (that should be the main thread). So, there is nothing wrong here. . .

But, **it seems that you are creating the model in a function that is called from the thread pool.** If you don't move the model to the main thread at the end of your function (and most likely you aren't doing that), **your model will be living in a thread that doesn't run an event loop**. It will not be able to receive events, this is just asking for trouble. Generally you should avoid passing `QObject`s between threads (when this is possible), and only pass data structures that you need.

---

I'll start from scratch, and implement the whole thing by subclassing `QAbstractTableModel`, Here is a complete minimal example:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <tuple>

class AsyncTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel{
    Q_OBJECT
    //type used to hold the model's internal data in the variable m_rows
    using RowsList = QList<std::tuple<QString, QString, QString> >;
    //model's data
    RowsList m_rows;
    QFutureWatcher<RowsList>* m_watcher;
public:
    explicit AsyncTableModel(QObject* parent= nullptr):QAbstractTableModel(parent){
        //start loading data in the thread pool as soon as the model is instantiated 
        m_watcher = new QFutureWatcher<RowsList>(this);
        connect(m_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<RowsList>::finished,
                this, &AsyncTableModel::updateData);
        QFuture<RowsList> future = QtConcurrent::run(&AsyncTableModel::retrieveData);
        m_watcher->setFuture(future);
    }
    ~AsyncTableModel() = default;
    
    //this is a heavy function that returns data you want the model to display
    //this is called in the thread pool using QtConcurrent::run
    static RowsList retrieveData(){
        //the function is heavy that it blocks the calling thread for 2 secs
        QThread::sleep(2);
        RowsList list;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            list.append(std::make_tuple(QString("A%0").arg(i),
                                        QString("B%0").arg(i),
                                        QString("C%0").arg(i)));
        }
        return list;
    }
    //this is the slot that is called when data is finished loading
    //it resets the model so that it displays new data
    Q_SLOT void updateData(){
        beginResetModel();
        m_rows = m_watcher->future().result();
        endResetModel();
    }
    
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return m_rows.size(); 
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return 3; 
    }
    
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
        QVariant value= QVariant();
        switch(role){
        case Qt::DisplayRole: case Qt::EditRole:
            switch(index.column()){
            case 0:
                value= std::get<0>(m_rows[index.row()]);
                break;
            case 1:
                value= std::get<1>(m_rows[index.row()]);
                break;
            case 2:
                value= std::get<2>(m_rows[index.row()]);
            }
            break;
        }
        return value;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QTableView tv;
    AsyncTableModel model;
    tv.setModel(&model);
    tv.show();
    
    
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

---

#### Note:

The example above shows how to load data from a function that blocks the thread for a long time into a model asynchronously. This is the case for functions that perform heavy computations. If your objective is to load data over the network, You should use the asynchronous API provided in [`QTcpSocket`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html)/[`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), there is no need to use the thread pool in these cases at all, but other than that, everything should be similar.

Comment: Correct thanks, +1 for noticing the model creation in a secondary thread & view/model recap.