# QThread pass result data to MainThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm thinking about how to pass result data from some worker thread back to client without copying. Worker lives in other thread and BigData inherits QObject. My idea is to change ownership of data:

```
class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent);
signals:
    void resultReady(BigData *data);
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        BigData *data = new BigData(this); // alloc new Data
        while (!dataReady) {
            ... // appending data 
        }
        // Data ready 
        // clearing ownership
        data->setParent(NULL); // data can't be moved to another thread with parent
        data->moveToThread(NULL);
        emit resultReady(data);
    }
};

void MainWindow::handleResult(BigData *data)
{
    if (currentData_) {
        delete currentData_;
    }
    data->setParent(this); // set new ownership

    // works only if data's thread is NULL
    data->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread()); 
    currentData_ = data;
}
```

Does it look good? Or there is more proper way to do it?

Comment: Is there any reason for `BigData` class to inherit `QObject`? Does it have its own signals/slots?

Comment: No, I just use QObject because automatic destruction BigData on it's parent destruction comes handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usually you use [`moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) to *push* an object from one thread to another.** This means that instead of doing `data->moveToThread(NULL);` in your `doWork()` slot, You can write `data->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());` to avoid setting the thread affinity to `NULL` and then changing that from the main thread. But after moving the `BigData` instance to the main thread, **Be aware of touching that `QObject` from the worker thread**. Another thing to note about is that, moving a `QObject` back and forth between threads might cause some side effects, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread):

> Note that all active timers for the object will be reset. The timers are first stopped in the current thread and restarted (with the same interval) in the targetThread. As a result, constantly moving an object between threads can postpone timer events indefinitely.

**Inherting `QObject` just for the purpose of memory management is an overkill**. `QObject` provides [much more stuff](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details) (Introspection capabilities, dynamic properties, signals/slots, thread affinity, event processing, internationalization ...) that you don't really need here.

If you are interested only in memory management, [Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Smart_Pointers) and [the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) have smart pointers that can implement object lifetime management by unique ownership or shared ownership semantics.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733747/2666212) for an example of a model that offloads data loading to the global thread pool and displays these data in the view as soon as they are ready. Notice that the model inherits `QObject` (because [`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) inherits `QObject`, since it uses signals/slots to inform the view of data changes) but there is no reason for the data structure that actually holds data to inherit `QObject`. . .

Comment: @Sorcerer , another thing to note about is that your code currently has a race condition (that just got my attention). What if the window is destroyed before `handleResult` is invoked? since `handleResult` is currently where you claim ownership  of your `BigData` object, Your `BigData` object will be leaked. Again, You should change your design as mentioned in my answer. . .