# In worker thread, can I move data object to main thread to avoid data copying

Tags: qthread

One common way to pass data (customized) between thread is to send the data as parameter of signal/slot between threads. This incurs data copying.

I wonder if I can move the data back to main thread before worker thread finishes and just pass the pointer to data object in signal/slot, to avoid data copying? Something like below. Will it work without copying the data?

In Worker thread:

```
workerStart()
{
    MyData* data=new MyData();
    ...
    data->moveToThread(MainThread); //data will be deleted as thread function finish if not move to main thread?
    Q_EMIT ImDone(data);
}
```

In Main thread slot that connects to ImDone signal of Worker:

```
WorkerDone(MyData* data)
{
    // use data via pointer
}
```

Comment: You only need to worry about synchronization, you are complicating too much. Copying actually solves this problem for you.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the note. So I should do "Q_EMIT ImDone(&data);" in my worker? What should I do if I'd like to store the copy in my main thread "WorkerDone(MyData data)"? Also for my information, is it true that "data->moveToThread(MainThread);" will prevent the data from being deleted when thread is done and quit? Thanks.

Comment: When thread is done, it won't delete your object. Only delete deletes an object or some other mechanism (like smart pointer, or, in the case of Qt, being a child of a deleted object). Just `emit imDone(*data);`

Comment: oh, I was mistaken. I meant the function is done not the thread. So after "emit imDone(*data);", workerStart() will exit so the MyData* data initialized in it will be deleted (is that right??).

Comment: You need to show more code, so we can see. Generally, the thread exits independently of any signal emits, but even if it exists, the signal will survive.

Comment: Just found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150691/qthread-pass-result-data-to-mainthread. Looks like it is sending pointer of data and "data->moveToThread(mainThread)" is indeed necessary?

Comment: It really depends on your code, generally, it's not necessary, as a `QThread` instance will automatically move itself.